# To pass the id and also to do e.preventdefault in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
              `import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
                  import { connect } from 'react-redux';
                  import { itemsFetchData,toggleDiv } from 
                      '../actions/sidenavaction';

                 class SideNavItem extends Component {
                     componentDidMount() {
                 this.props.fetchData 
                   ('http://58f5d2ccc9deb71200ceecef.mockapi.io/nav');
                        }


                   render() {

                        var Nest=function(par) {
                            const numbers = par.itemized;
                            const listItems = numbers.map((number) => <li 
                       key={number.sid}>{number.svalue}</li>);
                return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
                    };



             if (this.props.hasErrored) {
        return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
                   }

                if (this.props.isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading…</p>;
             }

               return (
                <ul>{this.props.items.map((item) =>         
        <ul key={item.id}  onClick=
            {this.props.toggleDiv.bind(this,item.id)}><a href="#">
             {item.value}</a>
            {item.sub && <div style={{display: this.props.hidden ? 'block' : 
             'none'}}><Nest itemized={item.sub} /></div>}           
                </ul>               
                )}
                    </ul>
            );          
         }
        }

              const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
            return {
          items: state.items,
         hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
             isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading,
        hidden:state.toggleDivReducer.hidden
                  };
            };

                   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
                 return {
                    fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url)),
                toggleDiv: (id) => dispatch(toggleDiv(id))
         };
            };

                export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
               (SideNavItem);`
```

I am able to pass id to my action mapdispatchtoprops but also I want the onclick to be fired only on the element on which I click and also I have implemented to toggle but where to apply the hidden prop because when I load the list the nested list is not hidden but on clicking on the links I am able to toggle them[Onload the nested links are also visible whereas it should be hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlSS0.png)

action
              `  export function toggleDiv(id){
                    return {
                       type: 'TOGGLE_DIV',
                       id:id

```
                     };
                      }`
```

reducer
                          `export function toggleDivReducer(state = { hidden: 
                           true}, action){
                              switch(action.type) {

```
                         case 'TOGGLE_DIV':
                         return Object.assign({}, state, {hidden: 
                         !state.hidden});

                          default:
                         return state;

                           }

                           }
```

Comment: onClick= {this.props.toggleDiv.bind(this,item.id)} , how can i write a function to do event preventdefault and also to pass id to my mapdispatchtoprops and also my toggle is not working as expected,I mean on load the nested values are also showing up but when I toggle then it hides but that is also getting applied to all the links

Comment: ok I am able to understand why the onClick is getting applied because I have given it inside a map function, but could anybody please help me as to where should I place me onClick so that it only applies to the element clicked upon

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65WZ0.png)Actually my understanding was wrong i guess when I use hidden props then on loading the application it works but my click event works on all the links .The toggle is not working as expected.
My updated code

```
render() {
  var Nest = function(par,leme) {
    const numbers = par.itemized;
    const listItems = numbers.map((number) => <li key={number.sid}>{number.svalue}</li>);

    return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
  };

  if (this.props.hasErrored) {
    return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
  }

  if (this.props.isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading…</p>;
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.items.map((item) =>         
        <li key={item.id} onClick={this.props.toggleDiv.bind(this,item.id)}>
          <a href="#">{item.value}</a>
          {item.sub && <div hidden={this.props.hidden}><Nest itemized={item.sub} /></div>}         
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );          
}
```

The click is getting fired for both the navigations

Comment: ok I am able to understand why the onClick is getting applied because I have given it inside a map function, but could anybody please help me as to where should I place me onClick so that it only applies to the element clicked upon